# How to not show app chooser Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an intent that dials a number as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(isTelephonyEnabled() ? Intent.ACTION_CALL : Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(number));
cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
callbackContext.success();
```

The function isTelephoneEnabled() just makes sure that a Telephony Manager exists:

```
private boolean isTelephonyEnabled(){
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)cordova.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    return tm != null && tm.getPhoneType() != TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE;
}
```

The issue is, an app chooser opens up and asks for instance if I want to dial using Skype or through the normal Phone app. How do I prevent the app chooser from opening up? I want it to go straight to the default option everytime (the normal phone).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just give you an idea to do what you want.
You can get the list of all the activities that may receive your intent. Use [PackageManager.queryIntentActivities](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) for it. This method returns a list of [ResolveInfo](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/pm/ResolveInfo.html) objects. And you may retrieve an Activity name out of [ResolveInfo](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/pm/ResolveInfo.html#activityInfo)

Then you should choose one activity, that you want to open, and send your intent to this activity (use [Intent.setComponent](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setComponent%28android.content.ComponentName%29) for instance).

Comment: Thanks I understand what you're saying. I want to send the intent to the same application everytime, the native phone application. How can I find the package name and information about that app so I can just do it manually rather than querying for it?

Comment: I can just  advice  to research this issue. Probably the normal Phone application has a standard name. Or at least you may eliminate some common applications you don't need (like skype and so on). On the other hand  a user may use an alternative Phone app, so probably it's better to ask him which application to use or to add an option to your application that selects a phone application.  I suppose such an option would be the best solution.